# What is meant by "framing" another's site?

Tags: html, iframe

I've been given a copy of a proposed site agreement in which one of the conditions is:

> ...each of us may for the Term:
>   ...frame the other's site

What is meant by "framing"?  I assume it might have something to do with an iframe embed or to capture part of our main page without additional logos and other such imagery?

Comment: Actually, I think (not with enough confidence to provide it as an answer) that it just refers to framesets.  Probably a legalese holdover from a bygone era.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that "framing" is basically hijacking your content and making it look like it's a part of my site, like you said, stealing content into an iframe.

From [Internet Legal Issues:Framing](http://www.publaw.com/framing.html)

> The use of framing technology was a central issue in the Washington Post v. TotalNews case that was settled a few years ago whereby several prominent news organizations, including The Washington Post, The Wall Street Journal and CNN brought a lawsuit against the Web-based news gathering site TotalNews. TotalNews was using frame technology and hyperlinking to display the news organizations' information on the TotalNews Web site and was surrounding the frames with its own advertising.

Comment: And now these same news sites willingly make their stories available via RSS.

Comment: Excellent answer.  Thanks for the reference.
...and yes - it smacks of hypocracy to bring a case like that and then syndicate your content.

Answer (score 2):

In that context, it sounds like simply doing an

```
<iframe src='http://www.test.com' title='My Test Frame'/>
```

If you're not sure, however, it's always a good idea to ask and see what it is they mean so there is no misunderstanding and, as usual, always get it in writing :)

G-Man

Comment: +1: "always get it in writing" - this is so true yet so often overlooked